# In EntityFramwork 6.2.0 I want to create shadow property (is EF 6 Support Shadow Property)

Tags: entity-framework-6

My Entity Is

```
class Student
{
    public long Id{ get; set; }
}
```

DB Context is

```
 public class StudentContext:DbContext
 {
     public StudentContext():base("name=cnName") {}

     public DbSet<Student> Student{ get; set; }

     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     { 
         modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().Property<DateTime> 
                                                ("CreatedOn");
         base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
     }
}
```

The exception is

> syntax error cannot convert from string to System.Linq.Expressions.Expression

on below line

`modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().Property<DateTime>("CreatedOn");`

What I did wrong is entity 6 support shadow property.